# Notification on question edit

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed some questions being interesting but they lack some vital piece of information to correctly answer it. Most of the time, it takes a user some time to update the question with the correct information.

Instead of waiting for this update, couldn't we have an option to just follow the post and get a notification when it gets updated? This way I could just keep reading up on other SO posts without having an extra tab open?

This would also solve the *"@username I've updated my post"* comments.

Comment: If you mark that question as a favorite, you'll be notified about any activity in your profile page already.

Comment: That is weird, because I've marked several questions with favorite and haven't gotten any notifications

Comment: Just tried it. I marked the question as favorite, it got edited and I didn't get a notification.

Comment: Not a notification in your inbox, but on your profile page you should see that there was an activity.

Comment: Ah I see how that works. It still requires me to check my favorites list, and/or have an extra tab open.