# Feature to "Adopt a Post"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

## Problem

I find myself in this often recurring pattern of going back into my account's action/vote history to check up on posts I've commented or voted on to see how they're doing. Some of the time there was some activity that now allows someone to help the OP further in some way. It doesn't necessarily mean the question has improved to the point that it can be reopened, but often there's something positive that can be done, anything from pointing the OP in the right direction to at least making them understand SO's system a little better.

This activity doesn't show up anywhere else; e.g. it could be comments the OP left without @-ing anyone, or the post was edited but *still* (correctly) rejected in the review queue. Either way it's nothing the original close voters or commentators would be notified about.

Anecdotally I've heard many times that other users fall into this same pattern of "checking back in" with posts. The thing is, it's very time consuming to do this, to repeatedly go over a list of posts one by one to see whether anything has changed.

## Proposition

To solve this problem, how about some way to be **actively notified**, in the inbox, about *any* activity on selected posts? This includes any edits, comments and new answers on the post. I'll tentatively refer to this as "adopting a post", so you can keep up with it to hopefully nurture it into a useful state, or at the very least provide some "aftercare" to the OP in some way or another. This would be entirely opt-in on a post-by-post basis.

The existing Favourites feature does not suffice here, since there are no **active** notifications and it still requires regularly checking in on a list of posts.

## Devil's Advocate

The obvious critique here is that we don't want to encourage help vampires in any way by providing them a solution. My counter arguments for that are:

- we've been avoiding that since forever, and it's obviously not working as a strategy to significantly reduce bad posts
- "adopting a post" is already happening by the people that do it, just very manually
- you're still free and encouraged to ignore help vampires and concentrate on the posts you feel stand an actual chance

## Advantages

- keeps "first responders" that have already interacted with the post in the loop instead of solely shunting it off to "passer-by" reviewers
- can get posts out of review queues faster and reduce queue workload if post reopens are "settled out of court" by the originally involved close voter(s)
- reduces frustration on the part of OPs "commenting into the void" without getting any feedback, and speeding up the close-reopen cycle
- last but not least makes an informally established practice more efficient

I see this as really having the potential to shape community interactions in a more positive manner and helping new users onboard more easily (or at least letting them down less harshly), all with a minimum of change.

Comment: Calling it "watching" a post would certainly sound less wierd.

Comment: Agreed. "Adopt" doesn't have to be the official terminology, but it describes better what this is supposed to be for for the purpose of this proposal.

Comment: Starring posts gives you a notification in the form of a counter on the starred post tab, with posts with activity highlighted in the tab.

Comment: @Martijn Yes, but as I said, that still requires manually checking in regularly. 1) That's a habit that has become annoying to myself even. 2) "Favouring" a post is IMO sending the wrong message for posts that are pretty bad. — Maybe the Favourites feature _can_ simply be extended to include inbox notifications, I'm not all against it.

Comment: I was hoping to see FR for actually "Adopting post" - like take ownership and responsibility for the question (maybe with -3 score as requirement)... Ohhh welll.... Consider better name. Well written proposal (and I really hope you know something that we don't - as public policy of SE so far  "don't look at meta for FR").

Comment: That’s why I used the term “starring”, not favouriting. You claim you need to check a list,but that’s no different from going through the inbox. Starred posts at least remain highlighted until you click on them.

Comment: @Martijn I see the red inbox notification regardless of what page I'm on in the entire SE network; and let's not kid ourselves, we're on SE all day long anyway in some capacity or another. To see the Favourites count, I need to specifically go to my account page, and I need to do that regularly if I want to notice changes in a halfway timely manner. Which is exactly what I *don't* want to do all day long.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311110/notification-on-question-edit

Comment: The last thing I need is more red inbox notifications. Perhaps we also need a way to de-adopt questions? I still don't see what's wrong with having a nicely-curated list that I can go look at when I want to know if there have been updates to my favorite questions. (And, importantly, that I can ignore when I'm busy. This is particularly important since the inbox is currently horribly broken, such that dropping it down once marks *everything* as "read", meaning I really do have to read it all at once, or I lose notice of it forever.)

Comment: @rene Yes, very related, and illustrating that this has been on the wishlist for some users for a while. Note that I'm including notifications about *comments* as well, which the other proposal doesn't.

Comment: @Cody Again, this would be entirely opt-in on a post-by-post basis. And sure, you would be able to "disown" the post again as well. And again, perhaps simply adding inbox notifications for Favourites would suffice. Remind me, does Favourite activity include new comments?

Comment: I would like this. I occasionally see posts by new users that I find interesting but can't answer, and would like to receive updates on. Navigating the flow of curation and all that is hard and it seems like such a feature would let us focus on the posts we think may be salvageable.

Comment: I use the browser extension [Stack Exchange Post Watcher](https://stackapps.com/questions/8278/stack-exchange-post-watcher-firefox-chrome-extension-to-watch-posts-for-any) to achieve this.

Comment: @Rebecca This is really something that needs to be integrated into SE itself. I'm not using Chrome nor Firefox for starters, and I'm not going to just for this. It also has the potential to really shape community interactions more positively, so shouldn't be a browser plugin workaround.

Comment: I was always in favor of being able to follow some posts more closely and getting notifications for them. Favorites just don't cut it. If there is a chance that some post might improve, I might want to reverse some of my actions, like close votes or down votes. I cannot manually (or even with favorites) track all of them. Such option would make SO experience more friendly, because some users would use it, and those who don't want to use it, can continue as they were.

Comment: Would that be something like [the h̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶h̶o̶l̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ mentorship initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up)?

Comment: @usr *[Jein.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jein)* It might ultimately solve most of that problem in a much less "invasive" manner, but it's not meant to give anyone the idea that they're being mentored. I wouldn't even want to display a counter of how many people are watching the post, like the Favourite star currently does.

Comment: Not displaying that post is watched would be great improvement over favorites. Not once someone complained that their "good" post has been closed and downvoted because how could it possibly be bad when it has been favorited few times already...

Comment: Is this just for questions, or would it be for answers, too?

Comment: @TylerH I was mostly thinking of just questions, but why not extend this to answers as well…?

Comment: There definitely is a need to be able to follow/favorite/adopt/watch answers, period, let alone for this specific reason, so I would prefer if it could be extended to answers as well. People have been asking for the ability to favorite answers for as long as the favorite questions ability was a thing, I think.

Answer (score 27):

I'm in favor of this.

Often times, I see myself coming across a post that I find interesting. Maybe the question itself is relatable, maybe it's a new user who is showing interest in learning this whole stack exchange thing and wants to get it right.

These things are hard. There is a steep learning curve to getting things right, and I think what leads to the frustration and burnout of so many curators is that we keep focusing on the negative. Anything that gets our attention via review queues is usually for a bad reason: not clear enough, off topic, bad answers, all that. It pre-disposes you to a pessimistic view of things.

Being able to augment your workflow with some positive developments to check up on seems like it could alleviate that or at least allow curators to avoid burnout for longer.

On top of that having an experienced user watch over your post is probably the least-friction way of dealing with the flow of curation a typical post is about to receive: There'll be someone to take extra time to get the asker to understand, maybe to help editing and clarifying. I know many of our rules seem kind of arcane if you're not used to them.

Overall a good idea.